# WEBSITE (PHP)TO EXE PACKAGE

Tags: php, windows-installer, exe

Is there a way to make a locally built website into an exe package for installation. im making a teaching program that is browser based and need to compile it into an installation package. seen the like of php desktop and nusphere phpDock and these don't make sense; too techical. just need an easy to use program. please help

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is lacks minimal understanding of the question.

Answer (score -1):

I think, general answer is "no". To launch php-site you need to have some web & database server (for example, Apache & MySQL), installed on local machine + php interpreter itself (with additional extensions, maybe). And installation of this software varies a lot depending on end-user OS.

But if you can strict supported OS - for example, to Windows-only - you can try something complex like Denwer, XAMP, MAMP and so on. But even these solutions can't be called end-user, because they need non-trivial knowledges.